# VSTO Word Add-In breaks Word Count / Page Position

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I've developed a Word Add-In using VS2013.

I see that when the Add-In is activated, Word stops displaying the Word Count and Page Position at the bottom of the page.

Needless to say, I have no code in the Add-In that deals with Word Count or Page Position.

This problem occurs on Word 2007/2010/2013.

Any idea what can cause that?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use Application.ScreenUpdating = false and forgot to set it to true again

Comment: No, I never use the ScreenUpdating property.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to create a new VSTO based add-in for Word. After building the add-in I open Word and see the Word counter and Page position numbers as usual. Most probably you did something in the add-in or installed other add-ins.

So, all is working fine with a sample add-in installed.

Comment: Hi, I know it generally works, but for my specific Add-In it does not. What can cause that problem? What kind of code can cause the Word Count to stop functioning?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured it out, and I'm laying it here for anyone else who stumbles on this issue.

Apparently, Word has a problem with animated gifs. I have one in my Add-In, and when it displayed - Word Count stops functioning.
After I've replaced it with static image - all went back to normal.

Hope I helped somebody...